# Strange screen on boot

Tags: boot, screen, decryption

Yesterday I noticed that I have a strange screen when I enter a password. I mean the password to decrypt hdd. The same screen and logo is present when I shutdown computer. I use Ubuntu 16.04 with Unity (but last time I installed Gnome to test it - is it connected with Gnome?). Have you ever seen this screen and logo?
[Strange screen when decrypt hdd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EtyY.jpg)

Comment: How did you encrypt your HDD? Did you do it during installation of Ubuntu?

Comment: The logo is related Ubuntu Gnome.